# Replacing Marker with PNG icons

Tags: google-fusion-tables

I've made a sample of fusiontable showing the different locations.
Somehow I am not able to find answer on how to replace the marker with my own png marker.

Here is the code : 
https://googledrive.com/host/0B-YzoR9nIS6zM3EyMk1qQmhSVWc/hrj.html

Fusiontable is accessible Publicly.

Idea is to repalce custom marker.
Html is generated from FusionTables Embed Link.

Later I wanted to showcase client information inside infoWindow.

Please guide how can I customize the marker ?
Marker Link : https://googledrive.com/host/0B-YzoR9nIS6zM3EyMk1qQmhSVWc/symbol.png (64pxx64px)

Thanks in advance for the help.
Regards
Mak..

Answer (score 0):

You can't use your own custom icons in a FusionTablesLayer, [only the icons](https://support.google.com/fusiontables/answer/2679986) that are [pre-defined](https://www.google.com/fusiontables/data?docid=1BDnT5U1Spyaes0Nj3DXciJKa_tuu7CzNRXWdVA#rows%3aid=1).

You can use the [Fusion Tables API v1](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v1/using) to query the table for the coordinates and use [Google Maps Javascript API v3 custom markers](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers#icons)

Comment: Seems need to learn programming then. I though would be easy to fix inside tables itself calling url for icon.

Comment: Or you could use one of the predefined icons.

Comment: Thanks Geocodezip got your own made reference yesterday by surfing through. http://goo.gl/Ke8kTH Just that I am not a programmer need to understand this code on how can I implement so it can show only one table marker like i've instead selctable.